# uwsgi failed to open python file /root/ ... /wsgi.py (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi, wsgi

/var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log:

```
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18-debian (64bit) on [Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022] ***

Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - compiled with version: 10.0.1 20200405 (experimental) [master revision 0be9efad938:fcb98e4978a:705510a708d3642c9c962beb663c476167e4e8a4] on 11 April 2020 11:15:55
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - os: Linux-5.4.0-92-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 26 16:13:00 UTC 2021
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - nodename: 185-46-8-164.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - machine: x86_64
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - clock source: unix
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - pcre jit disabled
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - current working directory: /
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - chdir() to /root/eva/lawyer
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 2623]
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - VACUUM: pidfile removed.
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 1647]
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18-debian (64bit) on [Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022] ***
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - compiled with version: 10.0.1 20200405 (experimental) [master revision 0be9efad938:fcb98e4978a:705510a708d3642c9c962beb663c476167e4e8a4] on 11 April 2020 11:15:55
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - os: Linux-5.4.0-92-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 26 16:13:00 UTC 2021
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - nodename: 185-46-8-164.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - machine: x86_64
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - clock source: unix
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - pcre jit disabled
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - current working directory: /
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/pid
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - chdir() to /root/eva/lawyer
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - your processes number limit is 1831
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket fd 3
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - setgid() to 33
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - setuid() to 33
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)  [GCC 9.3.0]
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55ae4c9e8c70
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - python threads support enabled
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - mapped 500256 bytes (488 KB) for 10 cores
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - *** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - added /root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ to pythonpath.
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - failed to open python file /root/eva/lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py

Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 28754)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 28759, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 28760, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 28761, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 28762, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 28763, cores: 2)
```

I don't understand the reason for the error: Tue Jan 11 15:27:45 2022 - failed to open python file /root/eva/lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py I can't understand why uwsgi can't open this python file. The path to it is right

myapp.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/eva/lawyer
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= lawyer.settings
wsgi-file = /root/eva/lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py
#module = lawyer.uwsgi:application
workers = 1
max-requests = 5000
#plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
plugins = python3
#virtualenv = /root/eva/venv
pythonpath = /root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
die-on-term = true
socket = /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = www-data
gui = www-data
```

Tell me, please, what could be the cause of the error and how to solve it?
This seems like an easy problem to solve. But I couldn't find information about it on the Internet

Comment: uwsgi is running as the user 'www-data' is the wsgi file and parent directories setup with the correct permissions so that user can read it?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. tell me, how can I check this? how do I grant access?

Comment: you can run `ls -la` in your directory to confim the file owner and group permissions. For the purpose of testing, I'd set everything in your Django directory to be accessible by `www-data` by running `chown -R www-data:www-data ./*` Probably a better place for the files will be in `/var/www`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your file permissions for the Django project.You have your WSGI worker configured to use the account 'www-data'. Either change this to an account that has access to the directories and file, or change the files permissions.

You can validate the file permissions by running `ls -la` in the directory. The third column shows the owner and the fourth column shows the group.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lbird lbird      548 Nov  3 11:52  default-soapui-workspace.xml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lbird lbird  2785280 Jun  5  2021  ntuser.dat.LOG1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lbird lbird  3256320 Jun  5  2021  ntuser.dat.LOG2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lbird lbird       20 Jun  5  2021  ntuser.ini
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lbird lbird     8677 Nov  3 11:52  soapui-settings.xml
```

You can change file and folder permissions by running `chown www-data:www-data ./*` in the project directory.

I do not recommend keeping the files in your root directory, that should be protected. Instead consider moving them to `/var/www` or `/var/app`.

To validate if its a permissions issue, you could change your uWSGI configuration to make the uid and gid root, but do not use this in a production setting.